# Composition of polynomial and logaritmic function

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $f$ be a computable function in $PSPACE$ It is true that Turing machine that computes $f$ can produce only $EXP$-size output at most. I see that $\log 2^n = n$ we can "control" the output. But, it doesn't convince me.

Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a Turing machine computing $f$. Suppose that it has $q$ states and $m$ tapes, that the tape alphabet is $\Sigma$, and that on input of length $n$, it uses at most $M(n)$ space. The number of possible configurations of the Turing machine is at most $N(n) = qM(n)^m|\Sigma|^{M(n)}$. In particular, if it runs for more than $N(n)$ steps then some configuration must repeat, and so it never terminates. Since the machine computes $f$, it does terminate, and so it runs in time $N(n)$. In particular, the output size is at most $N(n)$.

When $M(n)$ is polynomial, $N(n)$ is exponential ($2^{n^{O(1)}}$).

Comment: But $f$ is computable in PSPACE and so the Turing machine cannot use EXP amount of space including output. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fade2black Space is only measured on the work tapes. The output tape is read only, and, depending on the model, the head might only move to the right.

Comment: I got it, I usually assume work and output tapes are same and contribute to the space complexity unless the opposite is stated explicitly like we do in case $L$ and $NL$.